# Windows Service memory usage steady increase

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer, log4net

I have simple Windows service which sends HTTP requests on few timer's. I installed Release version of this service and after few days running of it I noticed memory usage increase from ~5MB to ~32MB. This made me worried, I rarely do anything for desktop so I really lack knowledge to figure out where leak is happening...
Maybe log4net object is growing?

Here I initialize my service and it's configuration:

```
   private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private Historian historian;
        private EndpointsConfiguration endpointsConfiguration;
        private readonly string endpointsJson;
        public Service()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            historian = new Historian(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Historian"].ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Substring(6);
                endpointsJson = File.ReadAllText($@"{path}\EndpointsConfiguration.json");
                var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    Converters =
                    {
                        new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
                    }
                };
                endpointsConfiguration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EndpointsConfiguration>(endpointsJson, jsonOptions);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Fatal("Nepavyko nuskaityti konfigūracijos", ex);
                return;
            }
        }
```

OnStart method:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        logger.Info("Servisas startavo");
        try
        {
            historian.Ping();
            logger.Info("Pavyko prisijungti prie Historian duomenų bazės");
            foreach (var endpoint in endpointsConfiguration.Endpoints)
            {
                var timer = new TimerWithContext(endpoint, endpoint.Interval)
                {
                    Enabled = true
                };
                timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await Timer_Elapsed(sender, e);
            }
            logger.Info("Suformuotos užduočių gijos");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Fatal("Nepavyko prisijungti prie Historian duomenų bazės", ex);
            OnStop();
        }
    }
```

Timer Elapsed (primary work of this service):

```
       private async Task Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Endpoint endpoint = ((TimerWithContext)sender).Endpoint;
        var endpointTags = endpoint.Tags;
        try
        {
            historian.RetrieveLiveValues(ref endpointTags);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Fatal($"Nepavyko nuskaityti naujausių tag'o reikšmių, Gavėjas:${endpoint.UrlAddress}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (endpoint.AuthScheme != null && endpoint.AuthKey != null)
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(endpoint.AuthScheme, endpoint.AuthKey);
                }
                object data = new { };
                switch (endpoint.SerializationOption)
                {
                    case SerializationOption.PECustom:
                        data = new DeviceComponents
                        {
                            SerialNr = endpoint.SerialNr,
                            MeterCode = endpoint.MeterCode,
                            ReadDate = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}",
                            DevCompValues = endpointTags.ToDictionary(tag => tag.DestinationName, tag => tag.Value.ToString())
                        };
                        break;
                    default:
                        data = endpointTags.ToDictionary(tag => tag.DestinationName, tag => tag.Value.ToString());
                        break;

                }
                var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                try
                {
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint.UrlAddress, content);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    logger.Info($"Duomenys perduoti gavėjui:{endpoint.Name}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Warn($"Nepavyko perduoti duomenų šaltiniui: {endpoint.Name}; Adresas{endpoint.UrlAddress}; Duomenų kiekis:{endpoint.Tags.Count}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 32Mb? It's very low for a .net app and not necessarily indicative of a leak. Call us again when it's 2 gigabytes :)

Comment: The first thing to do if you are worried about memory is to use a memory profiler.. There is no other reliable way

Comment: @TheGeneral I have used .NET memory profiler, but it only indicates high instance count of System bytes[] objects...

Comment: @CaiusJard I will try to run this service for longer then, thank you.